# Delete on CASCADE not working with sequelize/mySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using sequelize with mySQL and i want to set delete to cascade between 2 tables

```
db.Recipe.hasMany(db.Comment, { onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
db.Comment.belongsTo(db.Recipe, { onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
```

I have try several things but when i delete a recipe, mu comments set to null. May be there is something special with mySQL ? I have checked but all look like ok.

I tried to define the model recipe in the comment model with a reference, and some others things.